# Excel concerning sorting

Tags: microsoft-excel

In my excel sheet, I have a master tab that I import data into.  I've created additional tabs in my workbook that this data flows into.  The issue I'm having is that if I sort my master tab in anyway, it messes up the data in all of the other tabs.  In other words, the formula in the other tabs doesn't follow the master sort.

How do I correct this?  I have Excel 365
Thank you.

Comment: How are you moving the data into the other tabs? What formulas do you use, and in what ways does it get "messed up"?

Comment: I use the copy/paste (the formula) from the master tab into a location on the various additional tabs (not necessarily in the same location - different cell numbers).  when I sort the master tab, the data (formula) in the other tabs do not move with the new sort

Comment: @Scott - Can you please provide some sample data or screenshots?

Comment: @Scott,, it's common phenomena while Copy & Paste in case of formula,, since some of the formula does have absolute references,, so be careful about this !

Comment: You'll have to provide some examples. One way that might solve your issue is to put your data in tables, then you might have to reconstruct your formulas in the other tabs to table references. This should result in your other tabs matching the "resorted" master tab.

Comment: @Scott,, if possible share the WB on cloud and let me examine it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best/cleanest way I think is to use Excel's PowerQuery functionality. (Google is your friend) Depending on the source, perhaps you can even import it directly to your result tables without using a "master table" to which you import the data.

Good luck.